# Nvidia driver install on Ubuntu 22.04.3 TLS

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia, graphic-card

I tried to install `Nvidia driver` on my Asus laptop GU603H powered by `rtx 3060 max-q mobile graphic card`. I couldn't update my driver via GUI so I tried to `tty1` using following steps:

1- `purging` all Nvidia related packages
2- install driver via `.run` file

At the final stage installation a message can be seen indicating successful process. However, I encounter this message after reboot:

[image]

Also `nvidia-smi command doesn't work`, it shows message `implies unsuccessful installation` of drivers.

I'm new to Linux because of that can't whats going wrong here. How can I fix the problem? Any help such as links will be appreciated

Comment: It doesn't appear that those messages have anything to do with graphics drivers. It's best to install the Nvidia drivers from the Ubuntu repos if possible. What didn't work when you tried?

Comment: Simillar issue, I had a Lenovo Legion 5 Pro 3060 running the Nvidia drivers fine.
Now I have the Legion 5 Pro 4070, but whenever I install Nvidia drivers, I see these errors it doesn't boot. Unless I restart in recovery mode and remove everything related to Nvidia, then it works fine.
\_TZ.ETMD, AE_N are the symbols it shows as missing.
Plus there's a Bluetooth: hcio: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install NVIDIA driver on Ubuntu, use the [`ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`](https://launchpad.net/%7Egraphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa 
sudo apt update 
ubuntu-drivers devices  
sudo apt install nvidia-settings  nvidia-graphics-drivers-535
```

You will get the `nvidia-smi` again (a part of `nvidia-utils` installed as dependency)

Other method: [NVIDIA Driver Installation Quickstart Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/tesla/tesla-installation-notes/index.html#ubuntu-lts)

[Supported products for the 535 driver version.](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/210649/en-us/)

Comment: There's no need to add any PPA unless you need a driver version still not available in the release's normal repo.  The "other method" can and SHOULD be avoided, especially by newbies like the question's author.

Comment: @ChanganAuto The driver for RTX3060 isn't available in the official repo.

Comment: You're right but in that case the version to install is 535, not 525.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Right thx